# There are uncommitted transactions / Lock request time out period exceeded

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please assist. I am trying to write a script to change a data type of a column that has dependants in a table. So i decided to combine scripts and  start from creating a temp table to move the data away from the proper table so i can drop it and re create it with a new data type for the column in question. The combined scripts executed fine but now they seem to lock other transaction in the database and when i close the script i get the errors in the title. here is my code below...

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN  
        PRINT '1.Drop Temporary Table'              
        IF  EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM sys.objects 
        WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'EmptyDepot.StoreStockTakeTemp') 
        AND type in (N'U'))

        DROP TABLE  EmptyDepot.StoreStockTakeTemp       
        PRINT '====Table Dropped'

        PRINT '2.Create Temporary Table'    
        CREATE TABLE EmptyDepot.StoreStockTakeTemp
        (
            StoreStockTakeID        INT                     NOT NULL, 
            CntrNum                 VARCHAR(11)             NOT NULL, 
            DepotID                 INT                     NOT NULL, 
            StockCaptureDate        DATE                    NOT NULL, 
            ChUser                  VARCHAR(50)             NOT NULL, 
            ChDate                  SMALLDATETIME           NOT NULL, 
            ChStamp                 TIMESTAMP               NOT NULL,
        )       
        PRINT '====Temporary Table Created'

        PRINT '3.Populate Temporary Table'
        INSERT INTO EmptyDepot.StoreStockTakeTemp
        (
            StoreStockTakeID, 
            CntrNum, 
            DepotID, 
            StockCaptureDate, 
            ChUser, 
            ChDate
        )
        SELECT StoreStockTakeID, 
            CntrNum, 
            DepotID, 
            StockCaptureDate, 
            ChUser, 
            ChDate
        FROM EmptyDepot.StoreStockTake
        PRINT '====Temporary Table Populated'

        PRINT 'Begin Transaction'
        PRINT '================='
        PRINT '4.Drop Table'
        IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[EmptyDepot].[PK_StoreStockTakeID]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[EmptyDepot].[StoreStockTake]'))
        ALTER TABLE [EmptyDepot].[StoreStockTake] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_StoreStockTakeID]     

        IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[EmptyDepot].[UX_CntrNum_DepotID]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[EmptyDepot].[StoreStockTake]'))
        ALTER TABLE [EmptyDepot].[StoreStockTake] DROP CONSTRAINT [UX_CntrNum_DepotID]      

        IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[EmptyDepot].[StoreStockTake]') AND type in (N'U'))
        DROP TABLE [EmptyDepot].[StoreStockTake]
        PRINT '====Table Dropped'

        PRINT '5.Re-Create Table'
        SET ANSI_NULLS ON
        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
        SET ANSI_PADDING ON

        CREATE TABLE EmptyDepot.StoreStockTake
        (
            StoreStockTakeID        INT                     NOT NULL, 
            CntrNum                 VARCHAR(11)             NOT NULL, 
            DepotID                 INT                     NOT NULL, 
            StockCaptureDate        DATE                    NOT NULL, 
            ChUser                  VARCHAR(50)             NOT NULL, 
            ChDate                  SMALLDATETIME           NOT NULL, 
            ChStamp                 TIMESTAMP               NOT NULL,

             CONSTRAINT PK_StoreStockTakeID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            StoreStockTakeID ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON "PRIMARY"
        ) ON "PRIMARY"
        PRINT '====Table Created'

        PRINT '6.Populate Table'
        INSERT 
        INTO EmptyDepot.StoreStockTake
        (
            StoreStockTakeID, 
            CntrNum, 
            DepotID, 
            StockCaptureDate, 
            ChUser, 
            ChDate
        )
        SELECT StoreStockTakeID, 
            CntrNum, 
            DepotID, 
            StockCaptureDate, 
            ChUser, 
            ChDate
        FROM EmptyDepot.StoreStockTakeTemp
        PRINT '====Table Populated'

        COMMIT TRAN
        PRINT 'Transaction Committed'
        PRINT '====================='       

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    PRINT ERROR_NUMBER()
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    PRINT ERROR_LINE()
    ROLLBACK
    PRINT 'Transaction Rolled Back'
    PRINT '=======================' 

END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

Script has some problems..

- what happens if someone inserts rows while your script is executing?
- is it true you don't need constraint (UX_CntrNum_DepotID) in new table?
- what about indexes? there could be none thought..
- you probably could just rename temp table so you do not need extra insert..

About uncommited transactions- cant see reason, but maybe you started some transaction before executing the command described?